# How is possible in Swift to let the MVVM loading the application data?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm trying to adapt an MVVM code example (that works) but I'm not able to let the app load the data.

The error I obtain at runtime is an empty view with the loading function not called.

This is the App struct:

```
@main
struct SMT_testingApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var appData = ApplicationData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appData)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class containing the app data:

```
class ApplicationData: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userData: [SMTItemViewModel] = [SMTItemViewModel(smtItem: SMTItem(itemDesc: "", itemCreaDate: Date(), itemUpdDate: Date(), itemTags: [], linkedItemsUID: []))]
    
    var urlFile: URL {
        getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("/SMT.json")
    }
    
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    init() { loadData() }
    
    func loadData() {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlFile)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            userData = try decoder.decode([SMTItemViewModel].self, from: data)
            print("JSON data loaded")
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

This is the view model:

```
struct  SMTItemViewModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var smtItem: SMTItem
}
```

These are the classes of model:

```
struct SMTItem: Codable {
    
    var itemDesc: String
    let itemCreaDate: Date
    var itemUpdDate: Date
    var itemTags: Set<SMTTag>
    var linkedItemsUID: Set<UUID>
    
    init(itemDesc: String, itemCreaDate: Date, itemUpdDate: Date, itemTags: Set<SMTTag> ,linkedItemsUID:  Set<UUID> ) {
        self.itemDesc = itemDesc
        self.itemCreaDate = Date()
        self.itemUpdDate = Date()
        self.itemTags = itemTags
        self.linkedItemsUID = linkedItemsUID
    }
}

struct SMTTag: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    
    var SMTTagDesc: String
    
    var id: String {SMTTagDesc}
    
    init(SMTTagDesc: String){
        self.SMTTagDesc = SMTTagDesc.lowercased()
    }
    
     func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher){
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: SMTTag, rhs: SMTTag) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

And finally the View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: ApplicationData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(appData.userData) { smtItem in
                Text(smtItem.smtItem.itemDesc)
                //it would be smtItem.itemDesc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another issue is that is quite strange to me in the Content view is that I would access to the model properties using a "Text(smtItem.itemDesc)" instead of "Text(smtItem.smtItem.itemDesc)".

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: For your last question: each of the structs in your user data is a `SMTItemViewModel`.  It might be clearer to write `ForEach(appData.userData) { itemModel in
                Text(itemModel.smtItem.itemDesc)`.

Comment: Hi Philip, yes of course. But the problem is that in the example I've adapted the correct syntax is just "smtItem.itemDesc" instead.

Comment: Hard to comment on differences that aren't in view.  :)

Comment: You sure `loadData()` does not get called? Please verify with a breakpoint. This seems very odd since the function is invoked in the constructor. And the constructor is invoked on Applevel.

Comment: As you mentionend MVVM explicitly: `SMTItemViewModel` is not a viewmodel its a wrapper around your model struct and therefor a model itself ( no functionality only storage ). The naming is really confusing here

Comment: Yes, you have your naming conventions backward. `SMTItemViewModel` is not a view model. It should just be named `SMTItemModel`. Frankly, I would get rid of it and make `SMTItem` Identifiable and let that be your data model. `ApplicationData` itself really isn't a view model, it is your Source of Truth, which is fine. You don't have to have a view model for every view.

Comment: @Yrb > It was i did before. I changed because in all the MVVM template I got the source of truth is made of an array of view model object and not of model object. The role of view model it seems wrapping the model.

Comment: Not just wrapping, but publishing and containing logic that does not need to be in the view itself. This is why classes, not structs are used for a view model. However, writing a class that encapsulates a single instance of a Data Model, but doesn't actually supply the data is a bit non-sensical. The way you have done things, `ApplicationData` is more of the view model, then the struct `SMTItemViewModel` and the only reason I don't say it is a view model is that it is not restricted to just this view, but rather it is the data for the entire app.